iOS18 push notifications: subscribe to channel
For the new broadcast push notifications I am missing the documentation how a device subscribes to a topic / channel. Does anybody already figure it out?

Your app specifies the channel id when it starts a live activity see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending-channel-management-requests-to-apns
